# Real-time chat system on Laravel

Tags: database, web-development, chat, web, real-time

---

This is my first question to this website, although I'm not new. I have found all my questions answered and never really found a need to ask some of my own. But, I'm searching for over two days and found no reasonable answer to my questions.
I am about to develop a chat system for a web app which is built entirely on **Laravel** & **MySQL**. I need to develop a real-time chat system. Now I want to know:

1. Which technology/framework/library I should use to built that
   system?
2. Can I use **MySQL** or I need to use any **no-SQL** DB or any other DB for real-time chat?

**P.s:** *Through my research, I found that* **[Pusher](https://pusher.com/)** *could be a solution for a Laravel app. Can anyone tell me is it a good choice for handling chat messages of more than 50,000 users and would not blast up my server*?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance! **:)**